# Duda en argumento de llamada a función

Tags: c

Estoy teniendo problemas para llamar a una función debido a su segundo argumento de tipo matriz `array` de movimientos. Os lo dejo por aquí, necesito ayuda urgente. Gracias!

EN el .h:

```
void mapsolver_run(const char* map_file, const Move strat[][4], const int num_strategies);
```

En el .c:

```
void mapsolver_run(const char* map_file, const Move strat[][4], const int num_strategies){
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<num_strategies; i++){
        mapsolver_stack(map_file, strat[i]);
    }


}
```

En el main:

```
Move strategies [4][4] = {
        { RIGHT, LEFT, UP, DOWN },
        { DOWN, RIGHT, LEFT, UP },
        { UP, DOWN, RIGHT, LEFT },
        { LEFT, UP, DOWN, RIGHT }
        };

mapsolver_run(argv[1], strategies[0], 1);
```

La duda está en como llamar a la función en el segundo argumento, ya que me da error con `strategies[0]`. Gracias.

Comment: No soy experto en c, pero `const Move strat[][4]` espera una matriz de dos dimensiones, y `strategies[0]` es de una. Prueba modificando el parámetro a `const Move strat[4]`

Comment: Es que la matriz debe ser de 2 dimensiones.

Comment: Pues `strategies[0]` es de una. Llama con `strategies` a secas

Comment: Igual, ya lo he probado.

Comment: pointers to arrays with different qualifiers are incompatible in ISO C [-Wpedantic]
     mapsolver_run(argv[1], strategies, 4);

Comment: De todas maneras, no te he dado la bienvenida. Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. Por otro lado, te recomiendo eliminar lo de _necesito ayuda urgente_  , ya que no es muy bien recibido en la comunidad. Para ti puede ser urgente, pero para el que quiera y pueda ayudarte no lo es...

Comment: creo recordar que las matrices en C tenian como requisito tener todas las dimensiones definidas, a excepcion de la ultima, que podia no estarlo. Puedes probar con const Move strat[4][] en la definicion del .h y del .c?

Comment: La definición debe ser así, ya que nos lo han dado predefinida. EL problema está al llamar a la función desde el main.

Answer (score 1):

La única llamada que puedes hacer es:

```
mapsolver_run(argv[1], strategies, 1);
```

Aunque también podrías dejarlo así (que viene a ser exactamente lo mismo)

```
mapsolver_run(argv[1], &strategies[0], 1);
```

Pero como te han dicho en los comentarios, `const Move strat[][4]` es un parámetro que espera recibir una matriz... luego hacer un artificio para pasarle un vector es tentar al diablo.

> pointers to arrays with different qualifiers are incompatible in ISO C [-Wpedantic] Recibo este warning al hacerlo con mapsolver_run(argv[1], strategies, 1);

Ese error viene porque `strategies` no está etiquetado como constante:

```
const Move strategies [4][4] { /* ... */ };
```

La función está esperando una matriz de valores constantes... que no es lo mismo que una matriz constante (tamaño constante) con valores modificables... es lo que tienen los arrays declarados en la pila... no son exactamente iguales a los que usan memoria dinámica.

Comment: pointers to arrays with different qualifiers are incompatible in ISO C [-Wpedantic]
Recibo este warning al hacerlo con mapsolver_run(argv[1], strategies, 1);